# Storing stock portfolio in relational database?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I haven't done any major database work since university(10+ years ago) and wasn't sure the best approach to take when designing a database to hold portfolio.

The number of stocks in a portfolio is fixed(30 for example) but there's many portfolio I have. At first I thought I would create a unique ID thats the primary key and then a column for each stock name and the weight(I don't need to store information about the stocks such as price, if needed I can use the name to look that information up). I'm not sure if this is the best approach or if there's a better design?

I have two tables, one will have a current list of portfolio and another will have a historical version(both same format) and I'll compare them row by row and item by item to find similarities and other classifications. Initially I thought of just having a unique ID and then putting all the text of the stock information {IBM:3,goog:10,c:2}, but I'm not sure if parsing the text is effective or if maybe the database can do something to make parsing unnecessary.

I'm a bit new and am reviewing my SQL books but if anyone has any specific insight or anything I should be looking up/reading then that would be great.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you keeping the size of the portfolio fixed. I mean you can have a portfolio having less number of stocks.

stocks => (stockId, weight, name, details...)
portfolio ==> (entity_id, version_id, stock_id,...)
version ==> (version_id, user_id, createddate, last_updated,...)
user ==> (user_id, user_details...)

Explanation :: There can be many users, Every user can have many versions of their portfolios,
Every version can be many stocks mapped.

Comment: It's a optimization system, there are no users and The size is fixed...not sure if that can be a design advantage.